# How to enable shuffle mode in UWP MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player

I am using [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer?view=winrt-19041) with [MediaPlaybackList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackList?view=winrt-19041) to play `mp3` files in my app.

Playlist defined like this:

```
SongList = new MediaPlaybackList
{
    AutoRepeatEnabled = true,
    ShuffleEnabled = true
};
```

SongList is populated with 3 songs.

I play music using this code:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayerMusic = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayerMusic.Source = SongList;
mPlayerMusic.Play();
```

Every time this runs, the same song is played! Shuffle does not seem to work. Auto-repeat does work and the first song is played after the last one, but no shuffle!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play `mp3` files in shuffle mode, you need to delete the statement `ShuffleEnabled=true` within the statement `SongList= new MediaPlaybackList{…}` and add a statement `SongList.ShuffleEnabled = true;` above the statement `mPlayerMusic.Source = SongList;`. Like this:

```
SongList = new MediaPlaybackList()
{
    AutoRepeatEnabled = true
};
```

SongList is populated with 3 songs.

Play music using this code:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayerMusic = new MediaPlayer();

SongList.ShuffleEnabled = true;
mPlayerMusic.Source = SongList;
mPlayerMusic.Play();
```

Note, try to populate four songs into `SongList` and the statement `ShuffleEnabled=true` within the statement `SongList= new MediaPlaybackList{…}` may work.

Comment: That fixed it, but it goes against everything I know about object oriented programming! Can you explain why this works? Whether I set the property of an object as part of a declaration or a little bit later, should not make any difference. I'm confused!